# Access denied issue while mapping SharePoint site to network drive

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, internet-explorer, sharepoint-library, network-drive

A user has "Full control" permission on SharePoint Library; when using the Windows Explorer view or a mapped network drive led to Access Denied error. Added site to the Trusted sites list but still getting Access Denied error and to add the site to trusted sites list.

Comment: try to sign out and sign back in, that worked for Me, [map network drive access denied](https://code2care.org/sharepoint/access-denied-error-mapping-sharepoint-online-library-as-network-drive)

Answer (score 0):

**Authenticate to Office 365**:

Sign in to the SharePoint Online site by using your Office 365 work or school account credentials, and make sure that you select the Stay signed in option as seen in the following screen shot:
[image]

**Check the status of the WebClient service:**

To keep the connection after you restart the computer, make sure that the WebClient service is running.

More information for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/troubleshoot-mapped-network-drives

*Note:*

*Mapping a network drive uses WebDav, an older technology which is slower and less reliable than syncing SharePoint files with the new OneDrive sync client. The OneDrive sync client provides Files On-Demand, which allows you to access all your files in OneDrive without using local storage space.*